# How to start every opening of a file on some text label

Tags: vim, autocommand

I would like for my vim (actually, neovim) to jump always to a label I leave in the text (or the first one, if there is more than one). So, I have setup this autocommand:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead * call search('\$\$\$')
```

and hope that it would work. Unfortunately, `BufRead` seems like not enough, because when I open the file now, it just opens it at the top again.

So, I replaced `BufRead` with `BufEnter` (after trying `BufReadPost`, which didn’t work either), and now vim truly jumps to the label, unfortunately it is a way to eager to do it. It jumps to the label (and possibly even replaces the text) when I use spellchecker or basically any time I return to that buffer from anywhere. That is too much.

However, the main point is that I don’t understand, why that `BufRead` doesn’t work in the first place.

Comment: That autocommand should work. Is it possible you have another autocommand active that undoes your work? Try `:9verbose edit myfile.txt` to see all autocommands that are invoked as you open your file.

Comment: @Amadan easier to start vim without plugins, run the autocommand, and see if it works. Now you know something else is going on (or not)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Of course, that’d be the first step, to find out if it indeed “should work”, as internet strangers seem to suggest. I don’t see those as either-or... Knowing about `:9verbose` is still useful (rather than try to do the whack-a-mole of guessing which plugin is at fault).

Comment: Agreed! @Amadan just a useful first debugging step. [vi.se] has a whole post on debugging steps

Comment: Thank you, @Amadan for the reply. When trying it, I got https://paste.gnome.org/pdmpxm6u9, which doesn't seem to be that bad, but my auto-command doesn't seem to be activated at all.

Comment: Since all I see is `BufEnter` and `BufWinEnter` events, it seems you executed my command when your buffer was already loaded (so Vim just had to switch to it, without loading the file or creating a new one). Either destroy that buffer using `:bd` or start with a fresh Vim, _then_ try to load (or create) your file with `:9verbose edit`.

Comment: @Amadan Run fresh ``nvim`` (without any argument), and then ``:9verbose edit filename.rst`` and I got https://paste.gnome.org/ppuqzmmnj Difference could be in me using neovim (when tried with the Bram’s vim, it didn’t work either, but the output is A WAY more verbose).